# Golang read data from file and indicate a missing value

Tags: go

I am parsing a csv file which contains integer values, some of them might be missing:

```
1,2,3
1,2,
1,2,3
```

In my code I'm populating a struct with the data:

```
type Line struct {
    One   *int
    Two   *int
    Three *int
}
```

My current guess to handle missing values would be to use a pointer to an `int` in order to show whether the value is missing:

```
// if nil, then no value in file
l := &Line{}
// read and parse...
l.Three = nil
```

However, using this approach makes assingment to `*int` cumbersome:

```
l := &Line{}
// NOT POSSIBLE, NOT COMPILING (cannot use 5 (type int) as type *int in assignment)
l.One = 5
// FEELS WRONG, BUT WORKS
tmpInt := 5
l.One = &tmpInt
```

How to handle missing integer values?

Comment: It's possible to do what goprotobuf does and have a [helper function](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/proto#Int) that accepts an int. The return value is an int pointer whose value is what you passed to the function (example: `l.One = mypackage.Int(5)`).

Comment: Out of curiousity, why not use [the Reader from the CSV package](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/), which supports blank fields?

Comment: @TimCooper This is cool. I also thought about a helper function, but assumed there would a more idiomatic golang way of expressing missing values. The implementation of goprotobuf is: https://code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/source/browse/proto/lib.go#299, why not just: http://play.golang.org/p/gg0up2vfaQ

Comment: @bishop How does it handle blank fields? I checked the csv package before, but they only parse the data into string values. And you can have an empty string like `""`, but not for integers.

Comment: @Kiril:  You'll note that the function accepts an `int` but returns `*int32`. A new variables is required to make the conversion. For functions that accept and return the same datatype, your solution works fine.

Comment: @TimCooper Yeah, you are right. Somehow confused it because at first I thought `int32(v)` was a function call. Thank you!

Comment: In your use case, convert the string to integer with `strconv.Atoi`, taking care of special cases like lambda (do you want that to be `nil`, `0`, some other default), like with OneOfOne's answer.  While atoi is not particularly fast, I think that might be easier to maintain than your own CSV parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function to build your `Line{}` from a `[]string`, a simple [example](http://play.golang.org/p/aNQ1FgTOgx):

```
func NewLine(s []string) (l *Line) {
    fmt.Println(len(s))
    if len(s) < 2 {
        return
    }
    l = &Line{}
    if i, err := strconv.Atoi(s[0]); err == nil {
        l.One = &i
    }
    if i, err := strconv.Atoi(s[1]); err == nil {
        l.Two = &i
    }
    if len(s) == 3 {
        if i, err := strconv.Atoi(s[2]); err == nil {
            l.Three = &i
        }

    }
    return
}
```

Comment: This is a nice way to solve it, because of the fact that the default values of pointers are `nil`, and thus by not assigning anything you indicate that the value is missing.

Comment: Yep, that's how the json package handles it too.